# Java Flow.Subscriber - How can I unsubscribe?

Tags: java, publish-subscribe, java-9, java.util.concurrent, java-flow

I'm creating an user event system using JDK 9 Flow API, so I have a room (which implements `Flow.Subscriber<Notification>`), it may have many users and each user can offer (dispatch) updates at any time.

When a user enters the room, I subscribe the updates on the room `user.subscribe(this)`. But there is no unsubscribe, how can I unsubscribe the user when he leaves the room?

```
public abstract class Room implements Flow.Subscriber<Notification> {
    private Flow.Subscription subscription;

    public void addUser(User user) {
        user.subscribe(this);
    }

    public void removeUser(User user) {
        // How can I unsubscribe the user?
    }

    @Override
    public void onSubscribe(final Flow.Subscription subscription) {
        this.subscription = subscription;
        subscription.request(1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(final Throwable throwable) {
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(final Notification notification) {
        // ...
        subscription.request(1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete() {
        // User left
    }
}
```

User class:

```
public class User extends SubmissionPublisher<Notification> {

    ....

    public int offer(Notification item) {
        return super.offer(item, (sub, msg) -> false);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Subscription.cancel()`. I suggest you read my [blog series about implementing stuff with the Flow API](http://akarnokd.blogspot.hu/2017/03/java-9-flow-api-asynchronous-integer.html).